# how to get text value from button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to get the text value inside a button. example:

if I click on papier I want the alert to say papier how can I call the HTML text of the button. right now I get undefined instead of "papier" when I click on papier.

```
  <h1>Jeu de Roche,Papier,Ciseau</h1>
    <div id="conteneur">
        <div id="interface">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Roche</button></td>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Roche</button></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Papier</button></td>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Papier</button></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Ciseau</button></td>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Ciseau</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        function clique(x) {
            var element = document.querySelector("button").innerHTML;
            alert(x.element);
        }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would better to use attribute selector and fire addEventlistener.

```html
<h1>Jeu de Roche,Papier,Ciseau</h1>
    <div id="conteneur">
        <div id="interface">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" data-name="button">Roche</button></td>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" data-name="button">Roche</button></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" data-name="button">Papier</button></td>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" data-name="button">Papier</button></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" data-name="button">Ciseau</button></td>
                    <td><button data-name="button" class="button" type="text" >Ciseau</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-name='button']")
        
        buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(this.innerHTML)
        }))

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` in your `clique` function is already the element you clicked, you don't have to find it again, simply use `x.innerHTML` or better `x.innerText`:

```js
function clique(x) {
  alert(x.innerText);
}
```

```html
<h1>Jeu de Roche,Papier,Ciseau</h1>
<div id="conteneur">
  <div id="interface">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Roche</button></td>
        <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Roche</button></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Papier</button></td>
        <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Papier</button></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Ciseau</button></td>
        <td><button class="button" type="text" onclick="clique(this)">Ciseau</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need a selector you are passing the button as a reference to your handler.

you can use value inside the button as well, value could be more versatile in my opinion.

```js
function clique(btn) {        
    alert(btn.value);
    alert(btn.innerHTML);
    alert(btn.innerText)
 }
```

```html
<h1>Jeu de Roche,Papier,Ciseau</h1>
    <div id="conteneur">
        <div id="interface">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" value="Roche" onclick="clique(this)">Roche</button></td>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text"  value="Roche" onclick="clique(this)">Roche</button></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" value="Papier" onclick="clique(this)">Papier</button></td>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" value="Papier" onclick="clique(this)">Papier</button></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" value="Ciseau" onclick="clique(this)">Ciseau</button></td>
                    <td><button class="button" type="text" value="Ciseau" onclick="clique(this)">Ciseau</button></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `querySelector` will only pick up the first matching element.

Now you could use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) *but* in JavaScript there's a process called [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). It allows you to add *one* listener to a parent element that captures the events from its child elements as they "bubble up" the DOM. It makes your code and markup cleaner, and has one single point of failure rather than many.

```js
// Cache the container
const interface = document.querySelector('#interface');

// Add a listener to it
interface.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// Check the clicked element is a button, and
// log its text content
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('button')) {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Jeu de Roche,Papier,Ciseau</h1>
<div id="conteneur">
  <div id="interface">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><button>Roche</button></td>
        <td><button>Roche</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>Papier</button></td>
        <td><button>Papier</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button>Ciseau</button></td>
        <td><button>Ciseau</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score -1):

You can change your function like this

```
function clique(x) {
   alert(x.innerHTML);
}
```